# try-with-resource not supported in -source1.5

Tags: java, swing

```
try ( BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(f))) {}
```

I used jdk 1.8 and netbeans 8.0.2 .The edidor show the error:

try-with-resource not supported in -source1.5
(use 7 or higher to enable try-with-resources).
I cant understand what it says.guide me.

Comment: Which editor are you using?.. You have to change *compiler version* to compile with *your jdk version*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set netbeans to treat your project as java 7 (or 8) project.

Look here: [Netbeans documentation](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javase-jdk7.html). Specially at: "Checking the Project Configuration" paragraph.

Comment: I checked it properly assigned. and test it work correctly .but still same error

Comment: thank you .i check source/binary format in netbean . select jdk 1.8 .sam error displayed